MongoDB aggregation by date by unit
so I have this bunch of code:
# Mongo collection example (days are ISODate example dates):
# {dt: day3(year, month, etc.), value: 1}, {dt: day4, value: 2}, {dt: day5, value: 3}
# start = day1, end = day5
MONGO_PIPE = [
    {
        "$match": {"dt": {"$gte": start, "$lte": end}},
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": {"$dateTrunc": {"date": "$dt", "unit": unit}},
            "value": {"$sum": "$value"},
        },
    },
    {"$sort": {"_id": 1}},
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": None,
            "dataset": {"$push": "$value"},
            "labels": {
                "$push": {
                    "$dateToString": {"date": "$_id", "format": "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S"}
                }
            },
        }
    },
    {"$unset": "_id"},
]

In few words: it aggregates documents, that matches range of dates start-end, and group'em by unit (day, week, hour, whatever)
My output now if unit=day:
{
"dataset": [1, 2, 3],
"labels": [day3, day4, day5]  #example dates
}

What I need is to generate zero values for day1, day2. There are no documents matching dates day1 and day2. So output should look like this:
{
"dataset": [0, 0, 1, 2, 3],
"labels": [day1, day2, day3, day4, day5] #example dates
}

I know that $match is insufficient here, and I need to generate offset based on unit.
I am like 5 hours in this DB for the first time.
If somebody knows the answer - please let me know, thanks in advance

where is day 1 and 2 coming from. are those the dates filtered from the first $match

example did you mean something like https://mongoplayground.net/p/9ULc8e6Yguj

too complicated. found better solution. thanks for efforts, guys. like 10 minutes answer is rly dope (no sarcasm)!

or i see you meant the missing gaps (dates) in between the range. misinterpreted the question. i thought you want 0 for the dates in the db not between the given range

mb, I was in a hurry, and english is not my native :)

First of all: thanks for efforts, folks in comments.
But. I found ez solution in docs.
$densify is awesome.
final code:
MONGO_PIPE = [
    {
        "$match": {"dt": {"$gte": start, "$lte": end}},
    },
    {
        "$group": {
             "_id": {"$dateTrunc": {"date": "$dt", "unit": unit}},            
             "value": {"$sum": "$value"},
        },
    },
    {"$sort": {"_id": 1}},
    {"$densify": {"field": "_id", "range": {"step": 1, "unit": unit, "bounds": [start, end]}}},
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": None,
            "dataset": {"$push": {"$ifNull": ["$value", 0]}},
            "labels": {
                "$push": {
                    "$dateToString": {"date": "$_id", "format": "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S"}
                }
            },
        }
    },
    {"$unset": "_id"},
]

If you are dumb pythonist like me - consider, that bounds[lower, upper] upper is exclusive, so if u want it to be inclusive you should do
upper+ datetime.timedelta(microseconds=1)

or do any upper+1
I'll leave answer here for next generations :) ppl from 2050 hope ye doing well
